# Correct order for script files loading for gentelella template

Tags: php, jquery, html, smart-wizard, gentelella

I'm confused to how to solve this problem

this is the Gentelella layout template:

```
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <!-- Meta, title, CSS, favicons, etc. -->
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Gentellela Alela! | </title>
        <!-- Bootstrap -->
        <link href="{{ asset("css/bootstrap.min.css") }}" rel="stylesheet">
        <!-- Font Awesome -->
        <link href="{{ asset("css/font-awesome.min.css") }}" rel="stylesheet">
        <!-- Custom Theme Style -->
        <link href="{{ asset("css/gentelella.min.css") }}" rel="stylesheet">
        @stack('stylesheets')
    </head>
    <body class="nav-md">
        <div class="container body">
            <div class="main_container">
                @include('includes/sidebar')
                @include('includes/topbar')
                @yield('main_container')
                @include('includes/footer')
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- jQuery -->
        <script src="{{ asset("js/jquery.min.js") }}"></script>
        <!-- Bootstrap -->
        <script src="{{ asset("js/bootstrap.min.js") }}"></script>
        <!-- Custom Theme Scripts -->
        <script src="{{ asset("js/gentelella.min.js") }}"></script>
        @stack('scripts')
    </body>
</html>
```

As you can see there is an head part that load css and a footer part that's loads script files. 
In my single page implementation i put a part like this:

```
 @push('scripts')
    <script>
        var cancButton='{!! __('messages.tempCreat_txtCanc') !!}';
        var nextButton='{!! __('messages.tempCreat_txthNext') !!}';
        var prevButton='{!! __('messages.tempCreat_txtPrev') !!}';
    </script>
    <script src="{{asset('js/jquery-ui.js')}}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{asset('/js/mxClient.js')}}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{asset("js/app.js")}}"></script>
    <script src={{asset('/js/bootstrap2-toggle.min.js')}}></script>
    <script src="{{asset("js/jquery.smartWizard.js")}}"></script>
    <script  src="{{ asset("css/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js") }}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset("js/xml2json.js") }}"></script>
    <script src={{asset('/js/stepper2.js')}}></script>
    <script src={{asset('/js/validationJquery.js')}}></script>
    <script src="{{asset('js/funzioniEditor.js')}}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('js/jqueryEditorFunction.js') }}"></script>
    @endpush
```

as you can see "I push" files in the `stack('script')` part that is in the bottom of the page.

the problem is with plugin like:

```
<script src="{{asset("js/jquery.smartWizard.js")}}"></script>
```

That cause that you see the raw html, before that the plugin file is loaded...this is no good!
If im moving things to the head is a problem too, because the sidebar menu stops magically to works...

The function that render smart wizard is in a `$(document).ready(function(){}` function yet.

Comment: One thing you might want to take a look at is at all your single and double quotes. They are all mixed and some aren't closed the way they should.

Comment: There are several missing quotes in the src attributes of the second code snippet.

Comment: I use @extends('layouts.blank') in my view and I declare Js libraries  after the extend

Comment: there is no problem about single or double ' and " all works properly... and loaded. I found a workaround but its a workaround not a solution! ill post code later...

Answer (score 0):

I made this workround

- i put on the main div that contains all the wizard this:

  ```
                      <div id="smartwizard" style="visibility: hidden;">
  ```
- then simply after the function that render wizard I call:

  $('#smartwizard').css('visibility','visible');

I've tried even "toggle" or "show" but this is the only way thats make the trick works... So now the page is blank and then rendered with the complete wizard!